# Cannot assign a calculated value

Tags: python, pandas

I managed to calculate the standard deviation of a column using

```
df.loc[:,"Score1"].std()
```

but when I tried to assign this value to x and print out the standard deviation value using

```
x = df.loc[:,"Score1"].std()
print("x")
```

It only shows x instead of the standard deviation

Comment: `print("x")` prints the literal constant string `"x"`. `print(x)` prints the value/string representation of the variable `x`. Which one do you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're printing character "x".
Do `print(x)`